# VBA Error 50290 at ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Tags: excel, vba

The macro I created is able to loop quite a few times through "Reports()" before I get a message pop up saying "Microsoft excel is trying to recover your information" and an error for my vba script appears that says "Runtime Error 50290 - application-defined or object -defined error". This error occurs at :

```
                Set rng = Nothing
                Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange '<<<<Here is where i get and error
```

I'm unsure why this is happening since the code is able to loop several times and send out several emails and then stops randomly each time with the same error.

I was getting an error at :

```
                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = False  '<<<here
                    .ScreenUpdating = False  '<<< when i commented "EnableEvents" out, i got it here
                    .DisplayAlerts = False
                End With
```

But then I commented it out and moved it just below where ' Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' starts

Here is my code. I simplified it.

```
                a = Array("saveFile/", "FL Tests", "FL", "test1@email.com")
                Call Reports(a)

                b = Array("saveFile/", "FL Tests", "FL", "test2@email.com")
                Call Reports(b)

                c = Array("saveFile/", "FL Tests", "FL", "test3@email.com")
                Call Reports(c)

            Function Reports(a As Variant)

                Dim rng As Range
                Dim OutApp As Object
                Dim OutMail As Object
                Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
                Dim olNs As Namespace
                Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
                Dim olItms As Items
                Dim olMi As MailItem
                Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
                Dim olAtt As Attachment
                Dim MyPath As String

                Dim saveAs As String 'name for saving excel sheet in
                Dim emails As String 'list of emails the sheet is going to

                Dim departments As String 'string departments from array that need to be parsed
                Dim states As String 'string states from array that need to be parsed


                FilePath = "\" & a(0) & "\"

                departments = a(1)

                states = a(2)

                emails = a(3)


                today = Date
                day = Format(today, "dd")
                month = Format(today, "m")
                year = Format(today, "yyyy")
                d = Date - 1

                saveAs = state & "_" & month & "_" & day & "_" & year

                                Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
                                Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
                                Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
                                Set olItms = olFldr.Items
                                Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

                                 'With Application <<<<<<< Was getting error here so i moved it below
                                    '.EnableEvents = False
                                    '.ScreenUpdating = False
                                    '.DisplayAlerts = False
                                'End With

                                Set rng = Nothing
                                Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange '<<<<<<<Here is where i get and error

                                Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                                With Application
                                    .EnableEvents = False
                                    .ScreenUpdating = False
                                    .DisplayAlerts = False
                                End With

                                Set olMi = olItms.Find("[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & FL email & Chr(34))
                              If Not (olMi Is Nothing) Then
                                        For Each olAtt In olMi.Attachments

                                                 olAtt.SaveAsFile MyPath & state & ".xls"
                                                 Set wB = Workbooks.Open("Folder/" & current_report & ".xls")
                                                 wB.Activate

                                        Next olAtt
                                Else
                                End If

                 wB = ActiveWorkbook

                 wB.Save


                                With OutMail

                                    .To = emails
                                    .Subject = "Title"
                                    .HTMLBody = Hello World!
                                    .send

                                End With

                                On Error GoTo 0


                                ActiveWorkbook.Close

                                With Application
                                    .EnableEvents = True
                                    .ScreenUpdating = True
                                    .DisplayAlerts = True
                                End With


                              On Error Resume Next

                                Set OutMail = Nothing
                                Set OutApp = Nothing
                                Set olAtt = Nothing
                                Set olMi = Nothing
                                Set olFldr = Nothing
                                Set olNs = Nothing
                                Set olApp = Nothing

            End Function
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module and start by fixing the items it flags up.  FilePath will be `\saveFile/\\` - is that really what you want?

Comment: Thank you. No, I was simply trying to censor personal file information. I was in a hurry so I apologize for anything that seems odd. I know that conflicts with me asking for help when its an obvious error.

Comment: Please continue fixing your code and let us know once we have a working code sample in the above post. The following things still need fixing: (1) the first few lines such as `a = Array("...` followed by `Call Reports(a)`, etc. need to be wrapped into a `sub`. (2) `.HTMLBody = Hello World!` is missing two quotation marks (3) missing declarations as mentioned in the above comment (4) include missing references in the post such as `Microsoft Outlook xx.0 Object Library` (5) the line `olItms.Find("...` is also missing some quotation marks.

Comment: If you're getting an error with `Application.EnableEvents` then it would make sense to start there - no need to worry about anything else if something simple like that is failing.